# Problem creating a Custom Ribbon Action to Order Lists

Tags: visual-studio, ribbon, custom-list, custom-action, ordering

I attempted to create my first Custom Ribbon action to allow users to sort list items. But I failed miserably. the Action wont show in my ribbon at all and I am having trouble finding out what is wrong. I created an empty element and stuck the following code inside.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">


  <CustomAction
          Id="Ribbon.Library.Actions.AddAButton"
          Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
          RegistrationId="10000"
          RegistrationType="List">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition
          Location="Ribbon.List.Settings.Controls._children">
          <Button Id="Ribbon.Library.Share.NewRibbonButton"
            Command="NewRibbonButtonCommand"
            Image16by16="{SiteUrl}/_layouts/images/siteIcon.png"
            Image32by32="{SiteUrl}/_layouts/images/siteIcon.png"
            LabelText="Reorder Videos"
            TemplateAlias="o2" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler
          Command="NewRibbonButtonCommand"
          CommandAction="{SiteUrl}/_layouts/Reorder.aspx?List={ListId}" />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>

</Elements>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Chris O'Brien's samples and his excellent series of posts on developing Ribbon UI:

[Samples](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2011/10/my-ribbon-samples-from-spc11-session.html)
[Series first post](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/01/customizing-ribbon-part-1-creating-tabs.html)

Comment: thanks for the responses! I found this link was the most helpful. http://mpdsharepoint.blogspot.com/2012_01_01_archive.html

Answer (score 0):

Title is **required** attribute in CustomAction.

Answer (score 0):

I used this article to add an Order Column to my List and add the action to my content type for the list item. This is working now.

http://mpdsharepoint.blogspot.com/2012_01_01_archive.html

Next I am trying to Sort by this column in Code using Visual Studio and a CAML query. Although when Using U2U CAML Builder it wont allow this column to be picked. It is a hidden internal column. Has anyone had success doing this??

Thanks.